# Using popen() to build an array with fgets()

Tags: c

I'm trying to build an array of strings using popen(), but every index in the array is the last string returned. I'm ultimately just trying to get a directory listing of all files into an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = popen("find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -type f", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) { printf("Failed to run command\n" ); exit; }

    char path[999];
    char* rawdata[999];
    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
        rawdata[i] = path;  // Shouldn't this assign every index
        i++;                // a different string ?
    }
    pclose(fp);

    /* Below, every index is the same string ? */
    printf("\n%s", rawdata[0]);
    printf("\n%s", rawdata[1]);
    printf("\n%s", rawdata[2]);
}
```

Comment: since you are just doing a dirtree walk you can probably use http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#C instead popen on a possibly-missing binary granted, most systems do have find, but it will be slower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rawdata[i] = path;  // Shouldn't this assign every index a different string?
```

No. You are storing `path`, which is the name of an array and therefore *decays* into the pointer to the beginning of the array. So in fact, all of the elements of `rawdata` have the same value, and that is the address of the array `path`, which never changes.

To actually get the contents of `path` copied over to `rawdata`, you need to allocate memory for it in `rawdata[i]` (`malloc`) and then use `strcpy`. A shortcut for this exists in the standard library called `strdup`:

```
    ...

    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
        rawdata[i] = strdup(path);
        if (rawdata[i] == NULL)
            goto exit_no_mem;
        i++;
    }
    n = i;

    ...

    /* in the end */
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        free(rawdata[i]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
exit_no_mem:
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

Finally, note that if you are putting a hard cap on the number of elements you are reading, make sure you don't violate it. That is, once `i` reaches `999`, you shouldn't read more elements. Therefore:

```
    while (i < 999 && fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't yet found strdup() and wouldn't of cleared up the "path" pointer in any reasonable amount of time.